# decimal rounding off and '%'symbol is disappearing while exporting pandas dataframe to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When exporting my pandas dataframe with decimal values rounded-off and '%' symbol appended to values is getting disappeared. My pandas version is 1.1.5 with python 3.6.8.
I have also used xlsxwriter to format output export to excel, but that is also not working-

```py
writer = ExcelWriter('abc.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet1')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['sheet1']

fmt1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'0.0%'})
worksheet,set_column('G:G',None,fmt1)
worksheet.set_column('B:B',20)

writer.save()
```

other formatting like expanding width is working fine.
Why number format is not working here?

Updated -

Suppose this is my dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
header = [np.array([' ','X','X','Y','Y','Z','Z']),
         np.array(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
df[' ','A'] = ['n','n','m','m','m','p']
df['X','B'] = ['q','r','s','t','u','v']
df['X','C'] = [5,6,7,8,9,4]
df['Y','D'] = [1.5,2.9,3.6,2.5,7.1,0.4]
df['Y','E'] = [0.7,3.9,3.2,1.5,4.1,2.4]
df['Z','F'] = ['ab','bc','cd','de','ef','gh']
df['Z','G'] = ['5.5','2.6','8.6','4.5','0.1','3.4']
df.set_index(([(' ','A')]),drop=True,inplace=True)

I have applied styles on this df for dashboard, in dashboard it is coming properly but when exporting to excel the decimal round off and '%' symbol is going away -

df = (df.style.format('{:.1f}%', na_rep='-',subset=[col for col in df.columns if col[0] in ('X','Y') and col[1] in ('C','D','E')])).apply(highlight_cells, axis = None)\ .set_table_styles([{'selector':'th','props':[('border','1px solid black'),('font-size','8pt')]}])
```

Comment: *"Why number format is not working here?"*. The most common reason is that the cells being formatted contain strings and not numbers. You can tell this in Excel if the data is aligned to the left of the cell (strings) as opposed to the right of the cell (numbers). Can you add some sample data to your example to help determine what the issue is.

Comment: Could you provide a fully self-contained example (e.g. a tiny `df`, the required imports) to reproduce your issue, plus where exactly values are disappearing?